# Number of units per hour per day

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that shows information about container's visit: container's number, time in and time out.

If I'd like to know, how many containers I have now I could do:

```
SELECT count(nbr) from TBL
WHERE time_in <getdate() and (time_out is null or time_out>getdate())
```

I understand, that If I'd like to know such number on  1st Feb 2014 I'd do similar:

```
SELECT count(nbr) from TBL
WHERE time_in <convert(date,'2014-02-01')
and (time_out >convert(date,'2014-02-01') or time_out is null)
```

But now, I'd like to how many containers I had every hour since 1st Feb till now. Per hour.
I believe that the only way to do it is creating a procedure that will loop by datetime variable used in where clause:

```
declare @d datetime
set @d= convert(datetime, '2014-02-01')
declare @t table (T datetime, C int)

while @d<getdate
begin
  insert into @t
    select count (nbr) from TBL
    where time_in <@d and (time_out >@d or time_out is null)
  set @d= dateadd (hour,1,@d)

 end
```

But I find this solution very un-SQL (in SQL you supposed to say WHAT not HOW) and far from efficient.
Is there any better way to do it?

EDIT: just to make it clear example of data:

```
container           T-in         T-out
 A                12:00          15:10
 B                12:15          14:00
 C                13:10          14:10
 D                14:01          null
```

So as you can see:

```
at 12:00  - 1 container (A)
at 13:00  - 2 containers (A+B)
at 14:00  - 2 containers (A+C)
at 15:00  - 2 containers (A+D)
at 16:00  - 1 container (D)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use a [table of numbers](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html) or [calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html).
In the code below the table `Numbers` has a column `Number`, which contains integer numbers starting from 1. There are many ways to [generate such table](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1).
You can do it on the fly, or have the actual table. I personally have such table in the database with 100,000 rows.

The first `CROSS APPLY` effectively creates a column `CurrentHour`, so that I don't have to repeat the call to `DATEADD` many times later.

Second `CROSS APPLY` is your query that you want to run for each hour. It can be as complicated as needed, it can return more than one row if needed.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2014-02-01T00:00:00';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2014-02-02T00:00:00';

SELECT
    CurrentHour
    , CC
FROM
    Numbers
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT DATEADD(hour, Numbers.Number-1, @StartDate) AS CurrentHour
    ) AS CA_Hour
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT COUNT(nbr) AS CC
        FROM TBL
        WHERE
            time_in <= CurrentHour
            and (time_out > CurrentHour or time_out is null)
    ) AS CA
WHERE
    Numbers.Number < DATEDIFF(hour, @StartDate, @EndDate);
;
```

### Edit

Here is an example based on your sample data. You would have a proper table of numbers instead of `CTE_Numbers`. I made `CTE_Numbers` to make this script independent.

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (Container char(1), time_in datetime, time_out datetime);

INSERT INTO @TBL (Container, time_in, time_out) VALUES ('A', '2014-02-01T12:00:00', '2014-02-01T15:10:00');
INSERT INTO @TBL (Container, time_in, time_out) VALUES ('B', '2014-02-01T12:15:00', '2014-02-01T14:00:00');
INSERT INTO @TBL (Container, time_in, time_out) VALUES ('C', '2014-02-01T13:10:00', '2014-02-01T14:10:00');
INSERT INTO @TBL (Container, time_in, time_out) VALUES ('D', '2014-02-01T14:01:00', NULL);

DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2014-02-01T11:00:00';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime   = '2014-02-01T18:00:00';

WITH
CTE_Numbers
AS
(
    SELECT Number
    FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) AS T(Number)
)
SELECT
    CurrentHour
    ,ContainerCount
FROM
    CTE_Numbers
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT DATEADD(hour, CTE_Numbers.Number-1, @StartDate) AS CurrentHour
    ) AS CA_Hour
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS ContainerCount
        FROM @TBL
        WHERE
            time_in <= CurrentHour
            and (time_out > CurrentHour or time_out is null)
    ) AS CA
WHERE
    CTE_Numbers.Number < DATEDIFF(hour, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1
ORDER BY CTE_Numbers.Number
;
```

This is the result set:

```
CurrentHour                ContainerCount
2014-02-01 11:00:00.000    0
2014-02-01 12:00:00.000    1
2014-02-01 13:00:00.000    2
2014-02-01 14:00:00.000    2
2014-02-01 15:00:00.000    2
2014-02-01 16:00:00.000    1
2014-02-01 17:00:00.000    1
```

You can see that this approach will correctly calculate results for any hour. It is zero for `11:00`; it is 1 for `16:00`, `17:00` and further.

Answer (score 1):

Your instincts about your current code are good; you should avoid loops in SQL code if at all possible, because they perform terribly.

You can do this with [a recursive common table expression (CTE)](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/). Using CTEs requires SQL Server 2008 or later, but since you've indicated you're using 2008r2 this won't be a problem.

```
;WITH counts (nbr,time_in,time_out,present_until) AS (
  SELECT nbr
    ,time_in
    ,time_out
    ,DATEADD(hour, 1, '2014-02-02') AS [present_until]
  FROM TBL
  WHERE time_in < '2014-02-02'
    AND (time_out IS NULL OR time_out >= DATEADD(hour, 1, '2014-02-02'))
  UNION ALL
  SELECT nbr
    ,time_in
    ,time_out
    ,DATEADD(hour, 1, present_until) AS [present_until]
  FROM counts
  WHERE time_in < present_until
    AND (time_out IS NULL OR time_out >= DATEADD(hour, 1, present_until))
    AND present_until < '2014-02-03'
)

SELECT count(nbr) as [count],present_until
FROM counts
GROUP BY present_until
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18616/1/0) showing the results of this query. Please note that the dates used are changed slightly from the examples you gave.

Observe that the second half of the UNION is selecting from the CTE itself; this recursive self join in combination with adding an hour to present_until in the SELECT is what creates the list of times.

Note that present_until represents the *end* of the hour long interval; February 2 from 2:00 to 3:00 will show up as 2015-2-2 3:00. Also, any intervals with no containers present will be omitted from the results.

Comment: Unfortunately the results for that are wrong: it shows correct (more or less) information for the start date and 0 all the way to the end.

Comment: That's not wrong, it's the time_out value truncated to the nearest hour, as I stated in my answer and you asked for in the question. You wanted the number of containers per hour, by hour. You can't count per hour if you include the minutes, seconds, etc. Think about it; how would you even display that? If you want to know the exact time out, then you have to query for that separately, because it's different from what you asked for.

Comment: You've misunderstood me: I want to know how many containers I have by any given hour: one container arrived at 12 left at 3, 2nd arrived at 12:15 left at 2, 3rd arrived at 3 and never left. So at 12 I had 1 container, at 1 - 2, at 2 - 1 and again at 3 -  2 contaniers, at 4 - 1 etc.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and example data, I have changed my answer to reflect your requirements.

Comment: I believe its a good solution but very slow: my version using loop for period 2 months  takes about 5 minutes to run, this version takes about 15.